# IF $a,b,c$ are distinct reals how many roots does $(x-a)^3+(y-b)^3+(z-c)^3=0$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

IF $a,b,c$ are distinct reals how many roots does $(x-a)^3+(y-b)^3+(z-c)^3=0$ have?

Clearly ,$x=a,y=b,z=c$ is a solution. But are there any possibilities?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is $x=a+1, y=b, z=c-1$.

One more is $x=a+2$, $y=b$, $z=c-2$.

From here, you should be able to produce many more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x$ and $y$, there is one $z$ that satisfies the equation. Thus, there is a two-dimensional sheet of solutions in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$$
z=c+\sqrt[\large3]{(a-x)^3+(b-y)^3}
$$